# Why does task manager as administrator not show all tasks seen when NOT administrator?

Tags: administrator, task-manager

This is what I see as a user.  I am most interested in VBBatchPrint.exe.  I want to end the task, but I can't unless I log into task manager as admin.

[image: Taskman as user]

When I enter taskman as administrator, however, those items do not appear.  Even in detail, the actual PIDS do not appear

[image: Tasman as admin - missing PIDS]

1) Why does taskman as admin not show EVERYTHING?
2) How do I end processes I can't see as admin?

Comment: One is sorted by name and one by PID? I’m not sure what I’m supposed to see here.

Comment: Are you logging into the Administrator or running Task Manager as another user while logged into a different user?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a temporary comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of Rights. The "missing" processes are running at a higher level than the user account you are using.

To change this you can elevate the user account or you can run the processes at a lower level. (I am not suggesting either, security is there for a reason)